# Running IRSEND through custom service

Tags: pi-4, systemd, lirc, shutdown, reboot

I am totally new to raspberry pi and I am trying to get the IRSEND command to work in my custom service. My objective is when my pi is about to shutdown or reboot that it would execute a shell script that sends the command

```
irsend SEND_ONCE 'TVNAME' KEY_POWER
```

from my pi to the transmitter.
I wrote a service in /etc/systemd/system/myservice.service
Within that that service file I have:

```
[Unit]
Description=Turn off tv and lights on shutdown
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/bin/myscript.sh


[Install]
WantedBy=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target
```

After I created the service I did `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and `sudo systemctl enable myservice.service`.

When I start the service on the command prompt it executes just fine, but when I shutdown or reboot the Pi the TV is still on.
Any clues or pointers as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I am a little bit confused. Do you mean this: (1) Your service/ bash script with irsend command can switch off you home TV set, when running by a terminal command. (2) But when using systemctl to execute the same command when shut down or reboot, the TV refuses to go off?

Comment: @tlfong01 So when I execute my bash script through the command line everything works fine. Then when I execute sudo systemctl start myservice.service  on the command line everything works fine. But when I say sudo shutdown now  the tv does not turn off. I know it is executing my shell script when it shuts down because I have a python script that shuts off an led light that is controlled by a gpio pin.

Comment: how do you know that the script turns off the LED? ... it could be the *shutdown* that turns it off

Comment: @jsotola I know the script is turning it off because they are the neo pixel lights that are being powered by an external 5v power supply and won't shut off unless I unplug the lights from the power source or tell it through code to go low.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe LIRC service shuts down before your custom service has a chance to run?

Try adding

```
[Unit]
Requires=lircd.service
```

To your service file.

Another idea is to specify the relationship with shutdown/reboot targets in `[Unit]` section rather than `[Install]`. Normally, both should work but it doesn't hurt to try:

```
[Unit]
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target
```

Answer (score 1):

In your unit file you are using `ExecStart=` and yes, it is just doing what it is named: it will start the service. To run a script only on shutdown you have to use `ExecStop=` so your Unit should look similar to this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Turn off tv and lights on shutdown
After=graphical.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
User=pi
WorkingDirectory==/home/pi
ExecStop=/full/path/to/irsend SEND_ONCE 'TVNAME' KEY_POWER

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

---

**UPDATE:** because of the discussion in the comments, here some tests I have made to get an idea how it works.

Look at the properties to find runtime dependencies with:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl show shutdown-test.service
```

To get dependencies:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl list-dependencies shutdown-test.service
```

Documentation of the [System Manager Shutdown](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/bootup.html#System%20Manager%20Shutdown) phase.

To get shutdown messages from the systemd journal I made it persistent:

```
rpi ~$ sudo mkdir -p /var/log/journal
rpi ~$ sudo systemd-tmpfiles --create --prefix /var/log/journal
```

After reboot then look at the previous journal before booting with:

```
rpi ~$ journalctl --boot=-1
```

If you modify the `[Install]` section, don`t forget to:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl disable shutdown-test.service
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable shutdown-test.service
```

To be on the save side boot two times after modifying the Unit file. I have seen situations where on first boot only the changes are registered and take effect after the second boot. Use correct targets as shown in [System Manager Shutdown](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/bootup.html#System%20Manager%20Shutdown), in particular with `WantedBy`.

**Test Case 1:**

```
[Unit]
Description=Shutdown Test
DefaultDependencies=no
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/echo 'shutdown test executed'
[Install]
WantedBy=reboot.target poweroff.target halt.target kexec.target

# dependencies
shutdown-test.service
● └─system.slice

rpi ~$ journalctl --boot=-1 --unit=shutdown-test.service
-- Logs begin at Sat 2020-03-07 14:45:36 GMT, end at Sat 2020-03-07 18:41:01 GMT. --
Mar 07 18:40:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Shutdown Test...
Mar 07 18:40:05 raspberrypi echo[708]: shutdown test executed
Mar 07 18:40:06 raspberrypi systemd[1]: shutdown-test.service: Succeeded.
Mar 07 18:40:06 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Shutdown Test.
```

Note that the service is only started in the general shutdown stage but not stopped. This is for my opinion not a clean service management. In the shutdown stage there should services only stop not start.

```
# snippet from the journal
rpi ~$ journalctl --boot=-1 | egrep ' Stopp| Start| echo'
Mar 07 18:48:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping LVM event activation on device 179:2...
Mar 07 18:48:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped target Graphical Interface.
                                        ^^^^^^^
Mar 07 18:48:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped target Multi-User System.
                                        ^^^^^^^
Mar 07 18:48:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Availability of block devices...
Mar 07 18:48:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
Mar 07 18:48:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth service...
Mar 07 18:48:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Shutdown Test...
                                        ^^^^^^^^
Mar 07 18:48:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped target Sound Card.
Mar 07 18:48:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped target Login Prompts.
Mar 07 18:48:32 raspberrypi echo[715]: shutdown test executed
                            ^^^^
Mar 07 18:48:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Serial Getty on ttyS0...
--- snip ---
Mar 07 18:48:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Shutdown Test.
                                        ^^^^^^^
Mar 07 18:48:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Save/Restore Sound Card State.
Mar 07 18:48:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped dphys-swapfile - set up, mount/unmount, and delete a swap file.
Mar 07 18:48:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped rng-tools.service.
```

As you can see there are no dependencies because they are disabled. So the Shutdown Test is started after Stopped target Graphical Interface and Multi-User System. Stopping services is random.

**Test Case 2:**

With `DefaultDependencies=yes` the shutdown-test.service is never executed:

```
rpi ~$ journalctl --boot=-1 --unit=shutdown-test.service
-- Logs begin at Sat 2020-03-07 14:55:33 GMT, end at Sat 2020-03-07 19:06:49 GMT. --
-- No entries --
```

**Test Case 3:**

```
[Unit]
Description=Shutdown Test
After=graphical.target
[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStop=/bin/echo 'shutdown test executed'
[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target

rpi ~$ journalctl --boot=-1 --unit=shutdown-test.service
-- Logs begin at Sat 2020-03-07 14:56:33 GMT, end at Sat 2020-03-07 19:14:00 GMT. --
Mar 07 19:12:19 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Shutdown Test.
Mar 07 19:13:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Shutdown Test...
Mar 07 19:13:03 raspberrypi echo[715]: shutdown test executed
Mar 07 19:13:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: shutdown-test.service: Succeeded.
Mar 07 19:13:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Shutdown Test.

# snippet from the journal
Mar 07 19:13:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth service...
Mar 07 19:13:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Daily apt download activities.
Mar 07 19:13:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped target System Time Synchronized.
Mar 07 19:13:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Shutdown Test...
                                        ^^^^^^^^
Mar 07 19:13:03 raspberrypi echo[715]: shutdown test executed
                            ^^^^
Mar 07 19:13:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Bluetooth service.
Mar 07 19:13:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped LVM event activation on device 179:2.
Mar 07 19:13:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Shutdown Test.
                                        ^^^^^^^
Mar 07 19:13:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Mar 07 19:13:03 raspberrypi systemd[649]: Stopped target Default.
Mar 07 19:13:03 raspberrypi systemd[649]: Stopped target Basic System.
Mar 07 19:13:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped target Graphical Interface.
                                        ^^^^^^^
Mar 07 19:13:03 raspberrypi systemd[649]: Started Exit the Session.
Mar 07 19:13:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped target Multi-User System.
                                        ^^^^^^^
Mar 07 19:13:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Login Service...
Mar 07 19:13:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping dphys-swapfile - set up, mount/unmount, and delete a swap file...
```

Here is everything as expected. The service is starting on bootup and stopping within the shutdown stage like any other service. We have default dependencies and defined `After=graphical.target` in the Unit, which ensures that the Shutdown Test stops before target Graphical Interface. So my suggestion is: to avoid problems with dependencies you should use this Unit as template.

If your shutdown script still doesn't run, you should check if it find the same environment when starting from the command line. Maybe there is a path, environment variable, or library missing. Check the journal for error messages, execute `systemctl status myservice.service`. I have modified the Unit file to possibly meet some of these conditions.

Comment: Note that the OP is using "shutdown" as a WantedBy target, and ExecStart for shutdown should happen at about the same time as ExecStop for "multi-user". It should **not** run on RPi startup.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev **DefaultDependencies** are that shutdown.target conflicts with any other service that should start. The OP has set DefaultDependencies=no so I do not oversee the implication just in conjunction with shutdown.target. I will have a further look at it but I believe its better to run with DefaultDependencies.

Comment: So I went and changed my service script to match what Ingo had posted and it had no effect to turning off the TV. Then I went and added Requires=lircd.service under unit and placed Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target as @DmitryGrigoryev  had suggested and result was the same.

Comment: @Ikigai99 I have modified the example Unit and made some tests.